# Where are example Unique Devil stat blocks?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Flipping through the *Fiendish Codex II*, there are a few named devils listed as 'unique' but are provided no stat blocks, such as Titivilus, one of Dispater's Dukes and Barbas, a Duke of Mephistopheles. Are there official stat blocks, example stat blocks done by the community, or are DMs encouraged to make their own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although they were outlined in Fiendish Codex II they were blocked out in other literature.

**Titivilus, the Scribe of Hell**: Kobold Quarterly Summer 2007 on page 10

**Barbas, Duke of Hell**: [Dragon #76](http://static.annarchive.com/files/Drmg076.pdf) on page 30.

In the Dragon magazine you will also find several of the other Lords of Hell and Unique demons. It has them laid out within their respective circles of Hell. That magazine has the second part. The first part is in [issue #75](http://static.annarchive.com/files/Drmg075.pdf)

Comment: For further reading into the Dukes of Hell and other infernal beings check out more [Dukes of Hell](http://www.canonfire.com/wiki/index.php?title=Duke_of_Hell) and the posts about the Lords of Hell and Dark Eight are also worth reading for fluff at the bottom of the table.

Answer (score 4):

## Sometimes There Are Official Stat Blocks

*Wikipedia* has a surprisingly thorough listing of *Dungeons and Dragons* [devils](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_named_devils_in_Dungeons_&_Dragons) dating back, like, all the way, with a section on [Barbas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_named_devils_in_Dungeons_&_Dragons#Barbas) and a whole page on [Titivilus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titivilus_%28Dungeons_&_Dragons%29). The former has no official stat block, but the latter's *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* version by Wizards of the Coast appears on pages 43-4 in the electronic *Dragon* #360. He's CR 22.

As most unique devils will be high-level encounters, crafting your own can be time-consuming. Look at others' examples first and then try your hand at your own. I suggest using other high-level creatures as examples and going from there. Start with a [balor](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/demon.htm#balor) or [pit fiend](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/devil.htm#pitFiend), add a handful of class levels, pick better feats and gear, and go beat down some goodie-goodies.